# How do you get a section's ID

Tags: craft-pro

I need to access just the ID of a specific section.

I do that like this and it works:

```
{% set enroll = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('workshopEnrollments') %}
```

But when I do:

```
{% for e in enroll %} {{ e.sectionId }} {% endfor %}
```

or:

```
{% for e in enroll %} {{ e.id }} {% endfor %}
```

I get the error:

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("sectionId") on a string variable ("32")
```

However, when I view the variable inside my form what I actually see is exactly this

```
32Workshop EnrollmentsworkshopEnrollmentschannel1workshop-enrollments/_entry1
```

So my question is, how can I just display the id.  Both ".id" and ".sectionId" produce the same error mentioned above.

"32" is the id I want so it is the correct return, but this seems to show everything about it in a string and I need just the id. I am using getSectionByHandle because I have no other data to use in this particular view.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getSectionByHandle` doesn't return an array, but a single SectionModel - so you need to remove the `for` loop:

```
{% set enroll = craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('workshopEnrollments') %}

{{ enroll.id }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated for Craft 4:

```
{% set enroll = craft.app.sections.getSectionByHandle('workshopEnrollments') %}
```